# How can i use getApplicationContext in Java class (Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android

I want to  make my own library for getting the weather. I made the same in MainActivity and it works but when a put the same method in an another Class java i get error with Tosts and getApplicationContext methods. How can i fix it

```
   public class WeatherClass  {
    public static void getCurrentWeather(String location) {
        final String[] urlCityGetTemperature = {"https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/"};
        String urlCityGetId = "https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=";
        final String[] finishUrl = new String[1];
        String tempUrl = "";
        String city = "";
        city = location;
        if(city.equals("")) {
            //тут пишем код, если ползователь ничего не ввел в поле и нажал на кнопку
        }
        else {
            tempUrl = urlCityGetId + city;
            String finalCity = city;
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, tempUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("response", response);
                    String output = "";
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonResponce = new JSONArray(response);
                        if(response.equals("[]")) {
                            //уведомление о неккоректном вводе названия города
                        }
                        JSONObject jsonObjectZeroIndex = jsonResponce.getJSONObject(0);
                        int woeid = jsonObjectZeroIndex.getInt("woeid");
                        //tvRes.setText(output);
                        finishUrl[0] = urlCityGetTemperature[0] + output;
                        //тут мы будем получат температуру по id города.
                        StringRequest stringRequestGetTeperatureWithId = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, finishUrl[0], new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Log.d("finalLink", response);
                                String outputTemp = "";
                                String outPutWeather;
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("consolidated_weather");
                                    JSONObject jsonObectFromArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    int woeid = jsonObectFromArray.getInt("the_temp");
                                    outputTemp = String.valueOf(woeid);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext);
                        requestQueue.add(stringRequestGetTeperatureWithId);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, error.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

getApplicationContext and Toasts doesn't work.

Comment: you need to create a new thread to show the toast, because http call is asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass second parameter Context to getCurrentWeather, and then pass that context to The Toast.

Here is getCurrentWeather Method inside WeatherClass Like This,

```
public class WeatherClass  {
    public static void getCurrentWeather(String location,Context context){
        // Here is your fetch whether code

        // Your Toast like this
        Toast.makeText(context,"Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When you call this method from MainActivity, call Method like this,

```
getCurrentWeather(location,getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: Thank You! It wor
But I need to take only one parameter. It's study project. I get a task to create a library with one method  and one parameter. Is it possible?